# The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, int, MainActivity.ListViewItem[]) is undefined

Tags: android

I am new in Android Programming. I was doing a sample on ListView with different type of rows. I created a CustomAdapter which is extended from  ArrayAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public static final int TYPE_ODD = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_EVEN = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_WHITE = 2;
    public static final int TYPE_BLACK = 3;

    private final Context context;
    private final int resource;
    private ListViewItem[] objects;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ListViewItem[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
    }
```

Eclipse shows super(context, resource, objects); line as error "The constructor ArrayAdapter(Context, int, MainActivity.ListViewItem[]) is undefined"

I can't figure out why this is happening. Please help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type in the angle brackets (`<String>`) needs to match the data type in the array you are supplying (`ListViewItem[]`). In your case, they do not.

Most likely, you should:

1. Make this an `ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem>`
2. Remove `private ListViewItem[] objects`, as it is unnecessary and will get you in trouble -- use `getItem()` to access the array from the superclass

Most likely, you do not need `private final int resource` either, as it is unlikely that you will be using it, though I cannot rule that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {
    public static final int TYPE_ODD = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_EVEN = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_WHITE = 2;
    public static final int TYPE_BLACK = 3;

    private final Context context;
    private final int resource;
    private ListViewItem[] objects;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ListViewItem[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
    }


----------
see the first line of answer just change this line

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
to
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem>
```